# loop or sql query, which is faster?

Tags: php, sql, loops

It is a doubt that I have had for a long time. I had read once that in the cases of checking records one by one, it was faster to use a loop in the code than to travel them with a SQL query (the access time to the database makes it slower than the loop), but I have been testing for some logics and I see that it is not so. (the data obtained from the query to the base are returned faster), so what would be the most optimal way for these cases?

The cases to which they referred to me are like these:

```
$payMethods = PayMethod::has('payments')->get();
    $payments = collect();

    foreach ($payMethods as $payMethod) {

        $paid = 0;

        if ($payMethod->bankProvider->provider->type == 1) {
            foreach ($payMethod->payments as $payment) {
                $paid +=  $payment->price;
            }
        }

        $payments[$payMethod->name] = $paid;

    }

    return response()->json($payments);
```

with sql:

```
$payMethods = PayMethod::has('payments')->get();
    $payments = collect();

    foreach ($payMethods as $payMethod) {

        $sql = 'SELECT ROUND(SUM(a.price), 2) AS amount FROM payments a 
                JOIN paymethods b ON a.paymethod_id = b.id
                JOIN bank_provider c ON b.bank_provider_id = c.id
                JOIN providers d ON c.provider_id = d.id
                WHERE d.`type` = 1 AND a.paymethod_id = :paymethod_id AND a.deleted_at IS NULL';

        $paid = DB::select($sql, ['paymethod_id' => $payMethod->id]);

        $payments[$payMethod->name] = $paid[0]->amount;

    }

    return response()->json($payments);
```

note: the tests were made in chrome and the difference is notable in favor of logic with sql (5 to 6 seconds less with that of the loop).

Comment: It's unclear why you're asking a question you've already put to the test and received real-world results for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's better to send one query than multiple, because of mysql server cost and response time, but in your case you are using some kind of ORM, and due to lazy loading you are probably going to have N+1 (or worse) queries (you can read about that)

Comment: exact, and by eloquent is the time difference

Comment: If you would like more specific answer please add your entities code/configuration.

There is no option to give you specific time in second or sth